# Is there a way to hide a line of code from a public GitHub?

Tags: python, flask

I'm working with Flask. I want my repos public on my GitHub but I also don't want anyone seeing my database URI. Is there a way to hide that bit of code to the public? On Google, I see people talking about putting it in an environment variable but won't that also get pushed to GitHub?

Comment: The point of putting it in an environment variable is so *you don't actually hard code it in your source code*.

Comment: Variables set in your environment are not pushed to GitHub because they are not files. 
 Another common solution is to include your database URI in a configuration file that is not part of your repository, rather than hardcoding it in your application.

Answer (score 3):

These are going to be a generic examples.

#### Option 1: *.gitignore*

program.py

```
from config import dbURI

connect_to_database(dbURI)
```

config.py

```
dbURI = 'URI'
```

and modify your .gitignore (to skip it in your repo)

```
config.py
```

#### Option 2: *environment variable*

1. Set it as a environment variable
2. Load it in your code with `dbURI = os.getenv(environment_variable_name)`